# Is it possible to nest resource arrays in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
<resources>
    <array name="foo">
        <item>Foo!</item>
        <array name="bar">
            <item>Bar!</item>
            <item>Baz!</item>
        </array>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Is there any support for this? Or will I have to write my own xml parser?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use nested resource arrays like you have given as an example. It is however an option to make a one-dimensional array containing JSON or XML documents representing an array as each item. You will have to parse these arrays on your own though.